# Two approaches to combinatorics with deck-of-card problems

Tags: combinatorics

The problem I am examining involves a standard playing card deck (52 cards, 13 ranks, 4 suits, 2 colors). The question concerns the probability of drawing three cards in a row that are the same rank (e.g. drawing a 2 followed by a 2 followed by a third 2).

I have looked into two approaches to calculating this probability:

1. Out of the 52 cards, choose 1. From there, our next card can only come from the remaining set of three cards whose ranks match that of the first card. This probability would look like this:
   $$
   \frac{\dbinom{52}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{2}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{3}}
   $$
2. Out of the 13 ranks, choose 1. That gives us a set of four cards, of which we choose 3 like so:
   $$
   \frac{\dbinom{13}{1}\dbinom{4}{3}}{\dbinom{52}{3}}
   $$

I am pretty sure that the second approach is correct, but I have been taking the first approach a lot lately out of bad habit. Can someone break down for me exactly what is wrong with the first approach so I don't make this same mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first way, every "favourable" hand is counted $6$ times.  For example think of the hand that consists of the Queen of $\heartsuit$, $\spadesuit$, and $\clubsuit$. Among the $\binom{52}{1}$ cards, we could have any of the Queen of hearts, spades,  or clubs. And then we could have any of two remaining Queens.

Things will be OK if when you count ordered hands in the numerator, you do the same in the denominator. So your first numerator would be fine with denominator $(52)(51)(50)$.

Comment: I see so the probability would actually be $$\frac{\dbinom{52}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{1}} \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{51}{1}}\frac{\dbinom{2}{1}}{\dbinom{50}{1}}$$

Comment: That calculation is fine. With it you are counting the *same sort* of thing upstairs and downstairs. Double (or multiple) counting is a risk whenever one unconsciously breaks up a numerator as this and then that and then that. Luckily, after a few experiences  of double-counting one tends to be vaccinated against it.

Comment: Your second way avoids multiple counting but still lets us use a binomial coefficient at the bottom.

Comment: I notice that in numerator of my second answer, the 'top' numbers in the combinations multiply to 52, and the 'bottom' numbers multiply to 3 (52 and 3 being the combination on the bottom). Is there some sort of universal property that I can take away from that, or is it a coincidence?

Comment: The phenomenon happens fairly often. It is closely connected to the answer by Trevor Richards, where he observes that it doesn't matter what the first card is, all we need is to calculate the probability it is matched on second and third.

Comment: Another way of expressing the same idea is that after the first pick, there are $\binom{51}{2}$ ways to choose the "hand" of the next two cards, of which $\binom{3}{2}$ are favourable.

Comment: I see thank you so much! I think my biggest take away from this is your comment "With it you are counting the same sort of thing upstairs and downstairs". In my first approach, I am treating each card selection individually on the top with three separate combinations but grouping all three of those selections as one on the bottom, which I think is what is causing problems.

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you were counting the favourables,  you were counting ordered selections. One fix I mentioned is counting ordered selections also in the denominator. Another is to *deliberately* overcount on top, then divide by $3!$ to take care of the overcounting. But this only works if we are overcounting each hand by the same factor.

Answer (score 1):

The first card does not matter at all.  Therefore the probability you are really looking for is just the probability that your second card matches your first, and then that your third card matches your first two.  Thus the probability is:

$\dfrac{3}{51}\cdot\dfrac{2}{50}$

Note: This might be equal to either or both of your earlier tries, I did not check.  Did you check to make sure that your suggested answers are not in fact equal to each other?

Comment: Yes, I did confirm that my two answers are not equal. However, your answer matches with my second answer.